# Is there any idiomatic explicit use of mutex::lock() or unlock()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

The recommended way to use a `mutex` for locking a critical region of code is via RAII, i.e.

```
mutex_type mutex;
{ // start of critical region
  std::lock_guard<mutex_type> lock(mutex);   // first statement in critical region
  // ... do critical stuff, may throw an exception
} // end of critical region
```

so that when an exception is thrown within the critical region, the mutex will still be unlocked (by the destructor of `std::lock_guard`). However, this way the members `mutex::lock()` and `mutex::unlock()` are never explicitly called by user code.

**Q** What, if any, is the major idiomatic explicit use of `mutex::lock()`?

I'm asking, for otherwise there is no point in having `mutex::lock()` a public member promoting bad code (one which avoids `std::lock_guard`).

**Edit**
Since both `std::lock_guard<>` and `std::mutex` are defined in the same header, `std::mutex` could easily befriend  `std::lock_guard<std::mutex` and have its `lock()` and `unlock()` methods protected:

```
class mutex      // use only with lock_guard<mutex>
{
  friend class lock_guard<mutex>;         // support acquire-release semantic via RAII
  friend class scoped_lock_guard<mutex>;  // for supporting more complicated semantic,
                                          //     possibly remembering the mutex state.
  // ...
protected:
  void lock();
  bool try_lock();
  void unlock();       
};

class raw_mutex  // use if you absolutely must explicitly lock, try_lock, or unlock
: public mutex
{
public:
  using mutex::lock;
  using mutex::try_lock;
  using mutex::unlock;
};
```

**An argument** towards answering my question is simply that the only exception-safe way to use `mutex::lock()` is via RAII. Thus the only sensible explicit use must involve only `noexcept` methods between the calls to `lock` (or `try_lock`) and `unlock`. However, since `noexcept` is only suggestive and holds no promise whatsover, such use would be unsafe. **Q** correct?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/9431/2503 `thread_start_lock`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit your code looks rather scary. It's not at all obvious that `thread_start_lock.unlock()` is always called by the same thread that called `thread_start_lock.lock()`, in fact it looks like the opposite is the case.

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ??? So the point is that your code envokes UB? You should at least add an assertion that it is not.

Comment: What does UB have to do with it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit case of UB: calling `unlock()` on an unlocked mutex or on another thread than the one that called `lock()`. It's not clear that your code avoids these.

Comment: No, it certainly doesn't "avoid" that: it deliberately does that. As I already said, that is the entire point (read the comments in the code). I wasn't aware it's UB, but [damn](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.basic_lockable.unlock). If you have a moment, then, perhaps you could identify this as a problem with the code on the CodeReview.SE question, and suggest an alternative way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: One case I've seen (I will have to dig up where it is, but I think it's in libstdc++ somewhere) is that someone made a RAII class that calls `unlock()` on construction and `lock()` on destruction.  It's an odd case, but still.  Making this very difficult seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @DaveS such code wouldn't be exception safe, as it leaves the mutex in a locked state after destruction (called in stack unwinding after an exception was thrown). It only makes sense if there is another guard (in an outer scope), whose destructor `unlock()`s. However, such double-guarding could more clearly be implemented in a single object, like `scoped_lock_guard`.

Answer (score 4):

`lock_guard` isn't the only thing that needs to call `lock`/`unlock` on a `mutex`.  `unique_lock`, `lock`, `try_lock` and `condition_variable_any` all have to work on mutexes as well.  And that is just the standard types.  Friendship in this case introduces a tight coupling that becomes a hinderance.

Answer (score 1):

RAII can be (and should be) used when there is a static scope to which the lifetime of a resource can be bound, i.e. the resource should be initialized when the scope is entered and freed when the scope is exited.

There are situations, however, when there is no such static scope.
To illustrate this, consider variables as resources. We use automatic variables when there is a static scope to which we can bound them, but occasionally we need dynamic variables to control when they are created and destroyed.

The same can happen when we use `mutex`es for mutual exclusion. Consider this task:

Your program controls two resources, it has to read and execute a sequence of commands. Possible commands are:

- lock resource #1 : `1>`
- lock resource #2 : `2>`
- unlock resource #1 : `1<`
- unlock resource #2 : `2<`
- write `x` to resource #1 : `1x`
- write `x` to resource #2 : `2x`

your program can expect inputs like `1>` `1a` `2>` `2b` `1c` `1<` `2d` `2<`,
which makes the use of static scopes for RAII impossible if the program obeys the commands (the scopes would have to overlap partially).
So I think this illustrates one situation when explicit lock/unlock is necessary.

---

There is at least one other possible scenario which comes from the fact that mutual exclusion is not the only situation when one could use a `mutex`: it can be used for synchronisation as well.

Consider two parallel processes, `P` and `Q`, each with a designated point in their code. We require that `Q` cannot pass its designated point until `P` reaches its own. This requirement can be met by using a `mutex` initialised to `locked` state and placing a `lock()` operation right before the designated point of `Q` and an `unlock()` right after the designated point of `P`. It can be easily verified that this setup solves the problem.

Here `lock()` is placed in one process and `unlock()` in another, again there is obviously no static scope that can enclose them, so we need both to be accessible independently.