# mutex.lock vs unique_lock

Tags: c++, concurrency, locking, mutex

When should I prefer the first piece of code to the second, and do they have fundamental differences

```
std::mutex mtx;
mtx.lock();
... //protected stuff
mtx.unlock();
... //non-protected stuff
mtx.lock();
... //etc
```

and

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
... //protected stuff
lck.unlock();
... //non-protected stuff
lck.lock();
... //etc
```

I do understand that lock_guard is basically a unique_lock without the lock and unlock functions, but I'm having hard time differentiating a mutex and a lock using a mutex.

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873082/is-there-any-idiomatic-explicit-use-of-mutexlock-or-unlock

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, the `std::unique_lock` calls unlock on the mutex in its destructor.

The benefit of this is that in case some exception is thrown, you are sure that the mutex will unlock when leaving the scope where the `std::unique_lock` is defined.

Comment: So using simple mutex is not recommended, as having an exception could induce problems with the locks, which unique_lock prevents?

Comment: If you're code inside the lock can throw an exception, then yes. If you only lock once, and unlock at the end, than std::lock_guard will also do the job, and it's simpler than std::unique_lock

Answer (score 14):

Think of it this way:

```
// define a mutex
std::mutex mtx;
```

... much later ...

```
void something_safe()
{

  // code in these braces is a critical section
  {
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx); // equivalent to mtx.lock();
    ... //protected stuff
  }  // <---- however you leave this brace, equivalent to mtx.unlock();

  ... //non-protected stuff
}
```

Comment: this doesn't address any of the questions asked.

Comment: The edit queue for this post is full, but essentially what Richard is trying to get at is with a unique_lock you don't have to explicitly unlock the mutex - it unlocks when the unique_lock object goes out of scope.